# Why doesn't $(this) work here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/w5nAr/7/) JSfiddle have I two forms.

This is duplicated twice

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input id="element" signed type="checkbox" checked>
<label for="element">x</label>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and the JQuery looks like this

```
$('form').live('submit', function(){
    if ($("input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked')){
        $("label").show();
    }else{
        $("label").hide();
    }        
    return false;
});
```

I can't use ID's to distinguished between the forms, so I am left this `$(this)` I suppose.

If the last form is removed, it works as it should, but the problem is to get it work with many without using ID's.

However if I change the code to

```
$('form').live('submit', function(){
    if ($(this).("input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked')){
        $(this).("label").show();
    }else{
        $(this).("label").hide();
    }        
    return false;
});
```

It doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're using Firefox, install Firebug and keep an eye on the console, it will simplify things greatly.  If you're in Chrome, I think you have the developer tools already at your disposal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(this).("input[type=checkbox]")
```

is not valid code--you're using parens to invoke something, but have nothing in front of them to invoke.  You need to call `.find()` or `.children()` off your jQuery-ized form:

```
$(this).find("input[type=checkbox]")
```

Here is a condensed version for you:

```
$( 'form' ).live( 'submit', function()
{
  var $this = $( this );

  $this.find( 'label' ).toggle( $this.find( 'input[type="checkbox"]' ).is( ':checked' ) );

  return false;
} );
```

Comment: Awesome. How could you tell that this was the problem? Why, so to speak, do I have to use `.find()` on checkboxes and radio buttons, and not e.g. for text boxes, where I e.g. can just say `var title = this.elements.title.value` ?

Comment: The first sign of a problem was a dot (`.`) followed by an open-paren (`(`). That is not valid JS, whether you're using jQuery or anything else. Further, what `.find()` does for you is look below the elements in your collection for the thing your selector represents.  If you have a collection of DIVs (`$( 'div' )`) and want all paragraphs within those DIVs, you would call `.find()` off your DIV collection and pass the `p` selector to it: `$( 'div' ).find( 'p' );` OR `var divCollection = $( 'div' ); divCollection.find( 'p' );`

Comment: As for your example of `this.elements.title.value`, that is DOM1 navigation as opposed to jQuery. In that example, you're simply walking the DOM structure (JS object representation of the markup as exists in memory) to a specific element within. This is fine, but DOM navigation gets funny between browsers and doesn't offer a lot of smoothness or helper functionality like jQuery does.  Both are very very good to know, but jQuery levels the playing field between browsers and offers all sorts of functionality not provided natively.

Comment: @Sandra Schlichting: Although you could copy & paste my answer, I think you should accept JAAulde's answer. He put much more effort in his answer than I did.

Comment: @DanielB - thanks! It's cool though, you provided a perfectly valid answer which was easily understood by the OP.  Well done!

Comment: @JAAulde but from your answer and comments the OP is learning much more and may be isn't required to ask again a similar question ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You need a method name.

You could use the [`find()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method, which searches all descendants:

```
$(this).find("label").show();
```

...or the [`children()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method, which only searches *direct* descendants.

```
$(this).children("label").show();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code could look like this:

```
$('form').live('submit', function(){
    if ($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked')){
        $(this).find("label").show();
    }else{
        $(this).find("label").hide();
    }        
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]", this).is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('form').live('submit', function(){
    // Cache "this" reference
    var $this= $(this);
    if ($this.find("input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked')){
        $this.find("label").show();
    }else{
        $this.find("label").hide();
    }        
    return false;
});
```